# How to select the statevetor of a qubit in a multiqubit circuit in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, postselection

I need to use and plot the state of the first qubit in my multiqubit circuit,
but the issue is that I need to use post selection - I want only the results of which the other qubits in the circuit are 0.
for example, for this circuit:

[image]

I need to run it a few times, and see the statevector of qubit 0 for the case where qubit 1 is measured 0.

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`save_statevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.save_statevector.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.save_statevector) with `conditional = True`, like that:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
import numpy as np

circ = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)

 = [np.sqrt(0.8), np.sqrt(0.2)]
circ.initialize(, 0)
circ.initialize(, 1)
circ.measure(1, 1)
circ.save_statevector(conditional = True)

simulator = AerSimulator(method = 'statevector')

tr_circ = transpile(circ, simulator)
result = simulator.run(tr_circ).result()
data = result.data(0)
print(data['statevector'])
```